# PowerShell Show Menu

Tags: powershell

I have the next code written in PowerShell.
When I run the code, the Menu is shown, I enter the option 1..9 and the selected option is not called, the menu is shown again and again(see the screenshot[image]).
When I enter an option I want to be called that function related to each option entered then to display the message "The function has been called" and also to display the menu to enter a new option. (see the scrennshot - code in C++)[image]
Any idea ?

```
function PORII
{
    Write-Host " PORII was called"
}
function DXD-BODY
{
    Write-Host " DXD BODY was called"
}
function DXD-PAINT
{
    Write-Host " DXD PAINT was called"
}
function DXD-PTO
{
    Write-Host " DXD PTO was called"
}
function DXD-TCF
{
    Write-Host " DXD TCF was called"
}
function FIS-SERVERS
{
    Write-Host " FIS SERVERS was called"
}
function SERVERS
{
    Write-Host " SERVERS was called"
}
function Acronis
{
    Write-Host " Acronis was called"
}

function Menu
{
    param([string]$Title = 'Menu')
    Write-Host " ==================== $Title ==================== "
    while (1)
    {
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host " Press 1 for PORII: "
        Write-Host " Press 2 for DXD BODY: "
        Write-Host " Press 3 for DXD PAINT: "
        Write-Host " Press 4 for DXD PTO: "
        Write-Host " Press 5 for DXD TCF: "
        Write-Host " Press 6 for FIS SERVERS: "
        Write-Host " Press 7 for SERVERS: "
        Write-Host " Press 8 for Acronis Images: "
        Write-Host " Press 9 for Exit: "

        $a = Read-Host -Prompt "`n Enter your option "
        if (($a -eq 1) -or ($a -eq 2) -or ($a -eq 3) -or ($a -eq 4) -or ($a -eq 5) -or ($a -eq 6) -or ($a -eq 7) -or ($a -eq 8) -or ($a -eq 9))
        {
            switch($a)
            {
                1{PORII}
                2{DXD-BODY}
                3{DXD-PAINT}
                4{DXD-PTO}
                5{DXD-TCF}
                6{FIS-SERVERS}
                7{SERVERS}
                8{Acronis-Images}
                9{Exit}
            }
        }
        else
        {
            continue
        }
    }
}
Menu
```

Answer (score 1):

Your functions *are* being called, but that isn't obvious because `Clear-Host` is called right after, discarding the called function's output.

Apart from that, your code can be streamlined:

Instead of the `if (($a -eq 1) -or ($a -eq 2) ...` conditional, you can add a `default` branch to your [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement.

Also note that [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) always returns a *string*, whereas your conditionals operate on *numbers*; thanks to PowerShell's automatic type conversions, this isn't a problem in your particular case (with explicit or implied *equality* comparison), but it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Through the use of a hash table you can simplify your function while making it easier to maintain.

```
Function Menu {

  param([string]$Title = 'Menu')
 
  while ($TRUE) {

      $OptionHT = @{
        1="PORII"
        2="DXD-BODY"
        3="DXD-PAINT"
        4="DXD-PTO"
        5="DXD-TCF"
        6="FIS-SERVERS"
        7="SERVERS"
        8="Acronis-Images"
        9="Exit"
      }
 
    Write-Host " ==================== $Title ==================== "

    For ($Cntr = 1 ; $Cntr -lt $($OptionHT.Count) + 1; $Cntr++) {
       Write-Host "Press $Cntr for $($OptionHT.$($Cntr)):"
    }

   $a = Read-Host -Prompt "`n Enter your option "
   If (($a.length) -eq 1 -and ([byte][char]$a) -ge 49 -and 
                              ([byte][char]$a) -le 57)     {
     & ($OptionHT.[int]$a)
   }
     
  } # End While ($True)
       
} # End Function Menu
```

By placing your options in the hash table you only have a single point to make changes for called function names.

The if statement vs switch eliminates any value other than a single single number from 1 to 9 (note use of ASCII values to verify number input) from being processed. And since we have eliminated invalid inputs a single statement can be used to search the hash table for the function to execute.

**UPDATE:** Per the comments below you'll have to either trap the EXIT (9) with an If statement and exit or Create another Function and call it something like Exit-Program and place the Exit command there, I tested a function and it works.

Note: I didn't clear the console between writes of the menu so you could see your selection as mentioned in the comments you can add it where you deem necessary.

HTH

Comment: This is nice, however, the call operator `&` works on ScriptBlocks not on `strings`. To execute arbitrary code as `string` it would require `Invoke-Expression`. An easy fix would be to change the values on the `$OptionHT` hashtable for scriptblocks instead of strings.

Comment: Santiago, seems to work fine on my machine??? However, the Exit option does not work would have to add it as a function or another IF statement. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hmm maybe this was changed in PS Core? If I do `& ("Exit")` I would get an error however `& {Exit}` works as expected. Cant speak about the other calls cause I don't have those _cmdlets_ / _functions_ ? I was referring only to `Exit`.

Comment: Santiago, FYI: those functions are in the OP and only print that you called them.

Comment: Still, any option chosen would throw the `& : The term 'xxxxxx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` exception because of what I mentioned above.